# Is it possible to have one machine with a MSMQ queue and many machines with consumer services?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, msmq

I am thinking about using MSMQ for a set o services that may be called either by a server on the LAN as by mobile apps (through the Internet).
Because I am expecting a high number of messages, I was expecting to have one computer with the queue and N computers with services that consumer from this queue "remotely" (but still inside the LAN).

Reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1288214/hi-load-server-with-load-balancing-using-wcf-and-msmq), I understood that it is not possible when Zach Bonham says:

> When scaling MSMQ horizontally, there is an instance of a queue on each processing machine

Did I get confused or do I have to replicate the queue in each machine I want to have services running?

Thanks,
Oscar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The quote describes scaling horizontally (meaning multiple servers serving the queue), your case is vertical (meaning more consumers on one machine). As he describes, scaling vertically is perfectly fine, only thing to keep in mind is to have some sort of persistance mechanism should the server go down.

Comment: Ah, ok. I understood a little bit different: horizontal would be having multiple machines involved while vertical would be having only one machine running queue and services, being the number of services undefined. Thanks for the clarification! I will mark as answer as soon as the system allows me